# Comparing non-independent metaanalytic effect sizes

Tags: random-effects-model, meta-analysis, effect-size

I am running a random-effects meta-analysis on a collection of placebo controlled trials. Each trial reports on the effects of the drug and placebo on 'positive symptoms' and 'negative symptoms'.  I have calculated effect size estimates for drug-placebo differences for both positive and negative symptoms separately. I would like to know if it is possible to compare these two effect sizes to say whether the drug is more effective in treating positive compared to negative symptoms.

I imagine that this approach: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates would not be appropriate given that the estimates are not independent.

Any advice very much appreciated,

Thanks

Rob

Comment: Have you had a look at the literature for bivariate outcomes (such as test with a sensitivity and specificity)? There seem to be a lot of relevant sounding papers when I google.scholar for "meta-analysis bivariate".

Comment: Do you have correlations between the two outcomes? If so this is a fairly straightforward multivariate meta-analysis.

Comment: I do not have a correlation between the two outcomes at a individual patient level, I can of course calculate a correlation at the study level

Comment: The mvmeta Stata package is indeed perfectly suited for this type of correlated pooled analysis. Even if you are not aware of between-study correlations, you can use wscorr(riley) option: https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0156_1

Comment: If the OP wishes to stay with R then rma.mv() in the package he is using will work. Questions about coding are off-topic here but perusing the archives of the relevant R mailing list https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// and then perhaps asking there would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

These answers were provided at https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/2018-October/001228.html

Estimated a covariance matrix using the ClubSandwich package, and run the analysis with a range of values for ‘r’:

```
Vlist <- impute_covariance_matrix(vi = mydata_multi$vi, cluster = 
mydata_multi$studyid, r=0.5 )
```

Where yi is the calculated effect size, ‘posneg’ is the label describing whether the results of that row refers to positive or negative symptoms, and ‘studyid’  is a separate label for each study.

```
MultiMeta <- rma.mv(yi = yi, V = Vlist, mods = ~factor(posneg)-1, 
random = ~factor(posneg)|studyid, struct = "UN", data = mydata_multi)
```

Using struct="CS" assumes that the amount of heterogeneity is the same for positive and negative symptoms, which may not be the case.

To test for a difference between positive and negative symptoms, you can compute the contrast between the two estimates with:

```
anova(MultiMeta, L=c(-1,1))
```

Alternatively, fit the model with 'mods = ~factor(posneg)'. Then one of the two levels becomes the reference level (and hence the intercept) and the coefficient for the other level is the *difference* between the two levels. You should get the same p-value for this coefficient as when computing the contrast as shown above.

To add to Wolfgang's suggestions, it's also possible to test for differences between positive and negative symptoms using robust variance estimation. The advantage of doing so is that the hypothesis test/confidence interval is not predicated on having accurately imputed the within-study correlations between effect size estimates. Example code below.

James

```
library(clubSandwich)

# Separate intercepts model
MultiMeta <- rma.mv(yi = yi, V = Vlist, mods = ~factor(posneg)-1, 
random = ~factor(posneg)|studyid, struct = "UN", data = mydata_multi)
Wald_test(MultiMeta, constraints = matrix(c(-1,1), 1), vcov = "CR2")

# With reference level
MultMeta <- rma.mv(yi = yi, V = Vlist, mods = ~factor(posneg), random = 
~factor(posneg)|studyid, struct = "UN", data = mydata_multi)
coef_test(MultMeta, vcov = "CR2")
conf_int(MultMeta, vcov = "CR2")
```